# Import modules to run in browser snippet

Tags: javascript, browser, code-snippets

I just want to run a piece of code and need to import an external module in **browser snippet**
for example in below I wanted to import CryptoJS module. but I've came across error

```
function encrypt(message = '', key = ''){
var message = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key);
return message.toString();
```

}
I tried several ways including:

- import {cryptojs} from local source
- use require but no chance

Comment: I'd recommend using the native browser crypto instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto  If you really want to use CryptoJS, try a bundler like Rollup.

Comment: Hi Brad,I'll consider it but my question was not just about CryptoJS module, I'm after a way to use any other external modules in the snippet. like chartjs or etc